# Как посчитать сколько раз данные встречались в списке кортежей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список кортежей:

```
[('834319220',), ('753659610',), ('834319220',), ('753659610',)]
```

Со временем будет больше элементов в таком же виде.

Как посчитать, сколько раз число попадалось в списке?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

воспользуйтесь collection.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [('834319220',), ('753659610',), ('834319220',), ('753659610',)]

res = dict(Counter([x[0] for x in data]).most_common())
```

результат:

```
In [79]: res
Out[79]: {'834319220': 2, '753659610': 2}
```

или так - данные отсортированы по убыванию частоты:

```
In [80]: Counter([x[0] for x in data]).most_common()
Out[80]: [('834319220', 2), ('753659610', 2)]
```

Comment: 1) tuple и так hashable (см. ответ strawdog), 2) зачем все берут dict от Counter, он ведь и так выводит всё в понятном виде? 3) по умолчанию Counter и так сортирует элементы при выводе в порядке убывания частоты

Answer (score 6):

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [('834319220',), ('753659610',), ('834319220',), ('753659610',)]
print(dict(Counter(arr)))
```

> {('834319220',): 2, ('753659610',): 2}

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_ = {}

arr = [('834319220',), ('753659610',), ('834319220',), ('753659610',)]

for i in arr:
    if i in dict_:
        dict_[i] += 1
    else:
        dict_[i] = 1
```

Или так с использованием `set` и `arr.count`

```
dict_ = {el: arr.count(el) for el in set(arr)}
```

Comment: Зачем делать вручную то, для чего написана вполне стандартная библиотека (используемая в других ответах)?

Comment: в начале написал версию без библиотек, потом хотел добавит версию с библиотекой, но уже были даны другие ответы

Comment: Обычная история. Кто раньше успел - того и тапки )

Answer (score 1):

```
from collection import defaultdict

def counter_iterable_values(iterable):
    counter = defaultdict(int) # init all values 0

    for value in iterable:
        counter[value] += 1

    return counter
```

Реализация своего `Counter`.